# In Perl, is there any initialization framework like Spring?

Tags: java, spring, perl

I want to initialize some Perl objects from a configure file. So I wonder is there any framework to do it in Perl. Just like Spring in Java.

Comment: Are you using an object framework like Moose or Moo?

Comment: No. Is there some solutions in Moose or Moo?

Comment: I don't know, but I would like to do that in Moo. ;)

Comment: There are many different ways of writing the internals of a Perl object, so no solution will be guaranteed to work on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Bread::Board is probably the most sophisticated solution for this kind of thing.